# Bootstrap dropdown menu won't open

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I tried to implement many different solutions, but it seems that my bootstrap menu doesn't want to open. My code is the following :

The menus work in terms of directing to the proper page but the first one (which is supposed to be a dropdown) doesn't open.

Would you have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="/page1" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1</a>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/page1">Sous menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/page1">Sous menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/page_2">Menu2</a> </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: As you can see from the demo I created it works fine. You'll have to provide more insight into your situation.

Comment: You are totally right. I copied and pasted your code and it works now. I'll investigate what is different between my context and this.